# web2py - get id of current running task

Tags: web2py, scheduler

I'm trying to run a background job using web2py's scheduler.
Apart from processing the job, I also need to save the information of the user submitting it.

I've created a users_task table which stores the user_name and task_id's submitted.

Below is the sample code (in scheduler.py),

```
def task_add(user_name):
task_id = my_id # get the current task id ??
db.person.insert(name=user_name,task=task_id)
# do something
```

In the 2nd line of the code I need to get the id of the current task.

and I'm queuing the task using,

```
scheduler.queue_task('task_add', pvars=dict(user_name))
```

Is it possible to get the id of the current running task?
Also, please suggest if there is any other way of achieving the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some digging into source code I found the solution.
In gluon/scheduler.py,

```
def executor(queue, task, out):
     W2P_TASK = Storage({'id' : task.task_id, 'uuid' : task.uuid})
    _env.update({'W2P_TASK' : W2P_TASK})
```

W2P_TASK is an environment variable. So, to get the task id,

```
task_id = W2P_TASK.id
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

current_task = db(db.scheduler_task.task_name == 'task_add', db.scheduler_task.status != 'FAILED').select().last()
   current_task_id = current_task.id

All the details about the current running task can be fetched from the db.scheduler_task table and the information on the output of the task can be fetched from the db.scheduler_run table.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I guess the solution works when there is only one worker or one running task. But what if there are many workers/ many tasks running concurrently?